# ORA-04063: package body "TTMDBUSER.TTM" has errors ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "TTMDBUSER.TTM"

Tags: cme, event-system, web8.5

Currently we are not using `TopologyManager` and disabled the functionality development CME and checked the development CMS server event view log. The below log error is displayed. I want to avoid this error in event view log.

**`I am looking for solution and proposal for this issue.`**

> ORA-04063: package body "TTMDBUSER.TTM" has errors ORA-06508: PL/SQL:
>   could not find program unit being called: "TTMDBUSER.TTM" ORA-06512:
>   at line 1 Component: Tridion.TopologyManager.Service Errorcode: 0
>   User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE StackTrace Information Details: at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32
>   errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx*
>   pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32
>   isRecoverable) at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode,
>   OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx,
>   OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck) at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.Storage.RdbmsDataSession.Get[T](String
>   entityName, Int64 version) at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.Storage.CachedEntitySet`1.EnsureUpToDate()
>   at Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.Storage.CachedEntitySet`1.GetAll() at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.Storage.StorageManager.GetEntitySetT
>   at Tridion.TopologyManager.TopologyItem`1.GetList() at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Service.Controllers.TopologyItemController`1.Get()
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext() --- End
>   of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task
>   task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext() --- End
>   of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()

Comment: According to the error message, there are errors in the PL/SQL package TTM (which contains the Topology Manager Stored Procedures).  Was the Topology Manager database created properly?

Comment: Hi Sudhakar, please post what you have tried to resolve this. Did you also raise this with SDL support?

Comment: already we resolved issue. i will share sql script ....

Answer (score 2):

it was a permissions issue. here was our determination.
DBA must confirm that TTMDBUSER has following privileges:

```
Role => Connect which contains => 
    SYS PRIV => CREATE SESSION grantable => No
    SYS PRIV => SET CONTAINER grantable => No
SYS PRIV => CREATE SESSION grantable => No
TABLE PRIV => EXECUTE object => SYS.DBMS_LOCK grantable => No
TABLE PRIV => EXECUTE object => SYS.DBMS_UTILITY grantable => No
```